# How can I speed up the local server startup time of my Meteor app?

Tags: meteor, server, localhost

I'm contributing design visual design changes to a Meteor app and I need to make changes and see them in the browser. Only problem is that the app takes **minutes** to display on localhost. It reminds me of the time it takes a free herokuapp to wake up, only longer. Any idea what might be making it slow? Is this a problem that is common to Meteor apps?

Note: The dev team has profiled the app but there is some hidden wait time not reflected in the profile

Comment: Normally it's pretty fast - like seconds, not minutes.

Comment: @MichelFloyd I'm going to take that as a good sign that we have a fixable problem. ...but I guess that makes it hard to guess what the problem is. hmm....

Comment: When Meteor rebuilds the app after a change, you'll see a bunch of messages in the console where you started it. Which one(s) seem to take a very long time?

Comment: I suggest to start debugging with enabling profiler, via `export METEOR_PROFILE=1`

Comment: speed based on used packages and scripts. you should debug where is the slower perfomance. meteor totally almost very fast.

Comment: If you just change the CSS, I don't think you should expect to have to noticeably wait at all. So you may want to try and focus on big template changes (What are you using? React, Blaze, Angular?) in single steps and then make incremental CSS changes.

Comment: @Hans you make a good point about CSS changes not being that painful, but I'm also updating strings, etc. Still not that painful. ...but it's mainly that I see the development team having a lot of their time wasted by the server start time. We are using React with a bazillion packages because the app is built on top of an existing app and the feature scope is pretty big.

Comment: @pixelfairy Almost all web tools I've worked with take their sweet time to restart after a file change and Meteor has never struck me as being on the painful side, so it may be the complexity of your project, that is the issue here. Can you post a list of all the packages you are using (`meteor list`)? A beginner mistake I did was to run test if demo data was setup and if data migrations existed every single time the server restarted, which obviously can take its toll as your data increases.